# Jquery animate executes even if the condition is not satisfied

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate, settimeout

As someone advised me in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26513621/make-a-div-move-using-jquery), I'm using jquery in order to make a div move.
Now I want it to stop when it gets to 200 px from the left margin.
To do that, I'm using the following code:

```js
  var timeout = 100;
  var width = 200;
  var height = 500;
  var howmuch = 0;
  function move(before) {
 howmuch = before + 5;
 $("#obj").animate({'marginLeft' : '+=' + howmuch + 'px' } );
 if(howmuch < width){
     setTimeout(function() {
  move(howmuch)
  }, timeout);
  }
 else{alert('finished');
 }
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
 move(howmuch)
  }, timeout);
```

```css
  #obj {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div id="obj"></div>
```

But that's not working: I'm getting the alert when the box reaches 200px, but it doesn't stop.
What could be the problem?

Comment: two comments: You should have [edited](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) your other question rather than posting a new one, but if you *are* going to post a new question, you should provide a link to your "other question."

Comment: @Goodword thanks for pointing that out, I'm going to link my question, but it didn't include that specific problem, it was just about how to move a div with jquery and not about how to make it stop when it reaches a determined position. Should I have edited the old question anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that jQuery's `animate()` takes a certain amount of time to complete, and you're not allowing one animation to complete before starting another one.  You're also compounding your margin increase amount.  Instead of increasing by 5px, you're increasing by the previous margin amount and an additional 5px.  To accomplish what you are trying to do (multiple animations in a loop), you need to assign a callback.  Fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/o5d6z7qL/1/

```
var timeout = 100;
var width = 200;
var height = 500;
var howmuch = 0;
function move(before) {
    howmuch = before + 5;
    $("#obj").animate({ 'marginLeft': '+=5px' }, function () {
        if (howmuch < width) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                move(howmuch)
            }, timeout);
        }
        else {
            alert('finished');
        }
    });


}
setTimeout(function () {
    move(howmuch)
}, timeout);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're making things a bit complicated. Just set your `div` position to `relative` and animate `left` property, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/x99x70vw/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would it be possible to set the time the animation should take to complete using this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a timeout loop:

```
var howmuch = 200;
var duration = 4000; // = 200 / 5 * 100 from OP
function move() {
    $("#obj").animate({'marginLeft' : '+=' + howmuch + 'px' }, duration);
}
move();
```

Your example doesn't seem to stop because you have started many animations.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your animation increments bigger each loop, rather than incrementing a constant amount of 5 like your intention suggests.

```
$("#obj").animate({'marginLeft' : '+=' + howmuch + 'px' } );
```

So first loop it moves `marginLeft` + 5, next loop it moves it + 10 more for a total of 15, then +15 more yet again for a total of 30... do this about 40 times and you get a REALLY big number... try just using a constant incrementer instead:

```
$("#obj").animate({'marginLeft' : '+=' + 5 + 'px' } );
```

Also note that you increment loop repeats at a rate of 100ms, but the actual animation takes longer since you have not provided a duration for it, so you will still get the alert before it has finished animating.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I thought that I had to specify the number of pixels from the left margin rather than the actual position. If I use the code you posted, it all works!

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, its much easier than your example. Still, the reason yours is not working is because in the animate you are adding each time howMuch, which goes up to 200. So you are adding to your LeftMargin +5,+10,+15...+195. If you add all it sums up to 4000 px, which is where its stops. Correct animate would be:

```
$("#obj").animate({'marginLeft' : '+=' + 5 + 'px' } );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I thought that I had to specify the number of pixels from the left margin rather than the actual position. If I use the code you posted, it all works!

Answer (score 1):

You are incrementing with current margin every time in loop.

```
howmuch = before + 5;
```

here you calculate current margin, so change animate to set marginLeft to howmuch instead of increment with howmuch:

```
$("#obj").animate({'marginLeft' : howmuch + 'px' } );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I thought that I had to specify the number of pixels from the left margin rather than the actual position. If I use the code you posted, it all works!